# Access element's inline style property and overwrite it in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I have HTML DOM element coming from third party lib in my Angular 9 project. 
It has inline style properties like

```
 <div class ="extLib" style ="transform: scale(1, 1);"></div>
```

I tried to access it from component

```
 const svgContainer = (document.querySelector('.viewer-screens-base-scrContainer-api') as 
   HTMLElement).style.transform = 'scale(0.9, 0.9)';
```

However I am unable to overwrite its style properties.

Please suggest me right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a template reference on it:

```
<div #myReference class ="extLib" style ="transform: scale(1, 1);"></div>
```

And then in the TypeScript:

```
ViewChild('myReference') myReference: ElementRef;
```

Finally, in the concerned part of your code:

```
(this.myReference.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement).style.transform = 'scale(0.9, 0.9)';
```

Note: it is discouraged to use the native JavaScript API in Angular (`window`, `document`, `navigator`, etc...) because the code is supposed to be platform agnostic (it should be able to run on a browser as well as on a server with Node.js)